# How to get a drawn feature id in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

Using OpenLayers 4. I can get the list of drawn features by calling getFeatures(), but calling getId() on each feature returns "undefined".
Here is a screenshot from console with the list of drawn features.

[image]

As far as I see "c" is the "id" which is returned by getId() and  is "undefined" for all drawn features by default. So do drawn features have some automatically generated unique ids? The "xp" value seems to be the one. how can I get it then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547408/feature-ids-in-openlayers-3-are-undefined

Comment: You can use `ol-debug.js` to get meaningful variable names

Comment: Thanks for the hint @JGH. The variable is called ol_uid. Is it possible to get its value somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the variable content of a given `feature`, such as `xp` using

```
feature.xp
```

For instance, to label each feature using its `xp` value, modify the [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html) with

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: function(feature) {
    style.getText().setText(feature.xp.toString());
    return style;
  }
});
```

However since it is an internal variable name, there is no guarantee that it remains the same between versions. Similarly, there is no guarantee that a given feature keeps the same ID all the time. It is therefore dangerous to rely on this information, and even if it works today, it will eventually blow up one day.

As identified in the two [related](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163800/openlayers-3-access-feature-by-id)/[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547408/feature-ids-in-openlayers-3-are-undefined) answers and in @ThomasG77  answer, in order to use a reliable ID, you would need to manually set the ID when loading the data.

Comment: Thanks, JGH. It works. Do you happen to known if the "xp" variable name can get changed, e.g. at each OpenLayers release or is it safe to use it?

Comment: Unsafe: it related to the build system & it will change along time

Comment: @yaugenka see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

> So do drawn features have some automatically generated unique ids?

Features have generated id you can get with `feature.getRevision()`
This id is mainly useful to manage when editing a vector layer otherwise don't use them as a primary key as they can change.

If you need a stable id for each feature, you have to set the id yourself using the recipe already described at this related question ["OpenLayers 3: Access feature by ID"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163800/openlayers-3-access-feature-by-id)

Comment: It is a different variable, not the internal uid.